# SessionManager Timeout/Logout

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm currently using the examples found here http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.session.manager.html

In my autoload/global.php file I have the following:

```
'session'         => array(
    'config'     => array(
        'class'   => 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig',
        'options' => array(
            'name'                => 'otwebsoft',
            'save_path'           => __DIR__ . '/../../data/session',
            'use_cookies'         => true,
            'cookie_lifetime'     => 3600,
            'cookie_httponly'     => true,
            'cookie_secure'       => false,
            'remember_me_seconds' => 1800
        )
    ),
    'storage'    => 'Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage',
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            'Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr',
            'Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent'
        )
    )
)
```

I like how that the session expires after X amount of time and if the user was logged in, upon a page refresh the user is then automagically logged out and they must login again. However, I would like it so that if the user continues to surf the site, after X amount of time the session isn't killed off but perhaps just regenerated or something so that they are not forced to log back in again.

I am just not certain how or if this is possible to do both scenarios. If this is not possible, I could just raise the X time for session lifetime and live with that.

Does anyone have any ideas I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set cookie lifetime to 0:

```
'cookie_lifetime'     => 0
```

it will tell the browser to kill the cookie only after the browser is closed.

And define the server session storage lifetime:

```
'gc_maxlifetime' => 3600
```

So after 1 hour of inactivity the session storage will be cleaned up.